# Simple Morse code interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, morse-code

This is a simple Morse code interpreter with a CLI. It's a naive table-lookup implementation, and uses my-py for type checking. It automatically detects the input (English or Morse) and converts accordingly. It has the simplest possible CLI that I could think of. There is a [git repo here](https://github.com/bsima/morse).

I don't often write Python; I write Ruby for work and Clojure in my free time, but I do love Python and have a bit of experience with it. I welcome any suggestions on how to write more "Pythonic" code, simpler code or interfaces, or how to make the code more robust. Ideally, I want it to "just work" and be able to take even malformed data. Unfortunately, I think I need to keep the `msg` argument surrounded by quotes from the command line, otherwise the shell will interpret a single or double dot as the current or parent directory.

I'm considering using the [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) algorithm instead of a lookup table, but I'm not sure if that's worth it.

```py
import re
import argparse
from typing import Dict


eng = {
    "a" : ".-",
    "b" : "-...",
    "c" : "-.-.",
    "d" : "-..",
    "e" : ".",
    "f" : "..-.",
    "g" : "--.",
    "h" : "....",
    "i" : "..",
    "j" : ".---",
    "k" : "-.-",
    "l" : ".-..",
    "m" : "--",
    "n" : "-.",
    "o" : "---",
    "p" : ".--.",
    "q" : "--.-",
    "r" : ".-.",
    "s" : "...",
    "t" : "-",
    "u" : "..-",
    "v" : "...-",
    "w" : ".--",
    "x" : "-..-",
    "y" : "-.--",
    "z" : "--..",
    " " : "/",
    "0" : "-----",
    "1" : ".----",
    "2" : "..---",
    "3" : "...--",
    "4" : "....-",
    "5" : ".....",
    "6" : "-....",
    "7" : "--...",
    "8" : "---..",
    "9" : "----.",
    "," : ",",
    "." : ".",
    "!" : "!",
    "?" : "?",
} # type: Dict[str, str]


morse = {v: k for k, v in eng.items()} # type: Dict[str, str]


def morsep(msg: str) -> bool:
    if msg[0][0] in ['.', '-', '/']:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def morse_to_eng(msg: str) -> str:
    out = "" # type: str
    split_msg = re.split(" ", msg) # type: list
    filtered_msg = [e for e in split_msg if e] # type: list
    for char in filtered_msg:
        c = morse[char] # type: str
        out += c
    return("".join(out))


def eng_to_morse(msg: str) -> str:
    out = "" # type: str
    for char in msg:
        c = eng[char] # type: str
        out += "{} ".format(c)
    return("".join(out))


def decode(msg: str) -> str:
    "Main control flow."
    if morsep(msg) == True:
        return(morse_to_eng(msg))
    else:
        return(eng_to_morse(msg))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Translate English to Morse code, and vice versa.')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', help='Show the version.', action='version', version='Morse 0.1')
    parser.add_argument('msg', type=str, nargs=1,
                        help='The message to be decoded. Input type will be automatically detected and converted. \
                        Must be wrapped in quotes.')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    out = decode(args.msg[0]) # type: str
    print("{}".format(out))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Overall, this code was very simple and easy to follow. I just have a few nit-picks to point out.

---

The function syntax

```
def func_name(param_name: type) -> return_type:
```

is new in Python 3. However, it is not a very common thing to be used in Python, and I don't think it looks very pythonic.

Your code will work just as well without making functions like this, so I recommend that you stick to using the usual syntax:

```
def func_name(param_name):
```

---

This clunky statement:

```
if msg[0][0] in ['.', '-', '/']:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

can be reduced to a more pythonic and clean version:

```
return msg[0][0] in ['.', '-', '/']
```

---

Comments like this:

```
# type: list
```

are really unnecessary and just add noise to your code. Just from reading your code, someone reviewing it should be able to determine what type each variable is.

---

You need to do some more error catching.

For example, say you are translating a string from morse code to english. What if you encounter a character that is not a valid morse character? Your program will raise an error here:

```
for char in msg:
    c = eng[char] # <======
    out += "{} ".format(c)
```

Therefore, this is what you should do:

1. Encase that line in a `try/except`.
2. In the `except`, throw a custom `InvalidMorseLetter` exception.
3. Exit

Here is what I mean:

```
try:
    c = eng[char] # type: str
except KeyError:
    raise(InvalidMorseLetter)
```

where `InvalidMorseLetter` is:

```
class InvalidMorseLetter(Exception):
    pass
```

*Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24065533/3424096) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319675/3424096).*

In the code, I wrote to catch a `KeyError` because that is the error that would be raised if an invalid dictionary key is used.

You should use a custom exception because it specifically describes what went wrong with your specific code, rather than just a general `KeyError`.

You should do something very similar to this for when you are translating english to morse.

---

Thanks to [Zenohm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/68273/zenohm) for this.

In your translation functions, you should not be constantly modifying a single string each iteration:

```
c = morse[char] # type: str
out += c # <======================
```

The reason: python strings are immutable. Therefore, by constantly changing the string, you are actually creating a new string each and every time. This is very inefficient.

As Zenohm posted in the comments, you should be doing something along the lines of this:

```
return ''.join("{} ".format(eng[char]) for char in msg))
```

> While the modifying of a single string does not a bad habit make and
>   isn't really a problem here, I think it would be good if he started
>   avoiding the modifying of an immutable object right off the bat.
>   return ''.join("{} ".format(eng[char]) for char in msg) Could be used
>   in place of his original string modification and would help to
>   encourage better practice in future.

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes you suggested in the git repo. I included type annotations and comments because I'm using [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/). I'm trying to learn to use types better and more explicitly, so when I learn Haskell it will be easier (hopefully). So, I'm leaving them in for now.

Comment: Done! However, did you mean `except` instead of `catch` in the last two codeblocks?

Comment: @BenSima Ah yes! Sorry, I tried really hard to not forget that when writing the answer. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @BenSima mypy infers types from function definitions only, you can remove comment types.

Comment: On the subject of the statement that needed error catching, would it not be better for him to use a list comprehension instead of modifying a string?

Comment: @Zenohm I think it is fine that he is modifying a single string; what would you recommend, and why?

Comment: @SirPython While the modifying of a single string does not a bad habit make and isn't really a problem here, I think it would be good if he started avoiding the modifying of an immutable object right off the bat.
`return ''.join("{} ".format(eng[char]) for char in msg)`
Could be used in place of his original string modification and would help to encourage better practice in future.

Comment: @Zenohm Ah, thank you! I did not know that python strings are immutable.

Comment: @Zenohm I have modified my answer

Comment: @SirPython Yeah, Python's weird like that, as is C# and Java. (Personal opinion) But it's more efficient this way. On the plus side there is a mutable string type called [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bytearray).